# put values to a file using functions without creating new variables

Tags: sas

I am processing a dataset, the contents of which I do not know in advance.  My target SAS instance is 9.3, and I cannot use SQL as that has certain 'reserved' names (such as "user") that cannot be used as column names.

The puzzle looks like this:

```
data _null_;

  set some.dataset;  file somefile;

  /* no problem can even apply formats */
  put name age;

  /* how to do this without making new vars? */
  put somefunc(name) max(age);

run;
```

I can't put `var1=somefunc(name); put var1;` as that may clash with a source variable named `var1`.

I'm guessing the answer is to make some macro function that will read the dataset header and return me a "safe" (non-clashing) variable, or an fcmp function in a format, but I thought I'd check with the community to see - is there some "old school" way to outPUT directly from a function, in a data step?

Comment: SAS and PROC SQL allow you to use any valid name. In SQL you might need to either use name literal, 'user'n, or set DQUOTE=ANSI option and use "user".

Comment: by jove - the dreaded 'name literals'n might be the answer, can simply enforce `validvarname=v7` on the source and - `'job done'n`?

Comment: Friendly reminder there's the NLITERAL() function as well to format names into the proper format.

Comment: Note that NLITERAL() will not convert USER into 'USER'n because it is not an invalid name to SAS.  The issue was that it was reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary array?

```
34         data _null_;
35            set sashelp.class;
36            array _n[*] _numeric_;
37            array _f[3] _temporary_;
38            put _n_ @;
39            do _n_ = 1 to dim(_f);
40               _f[_n_] = log(_n[_n_]);
41               put _f[_n_]= @;
42               end;
43            put ;
44            run;

1 _f[1]=2.6390573296 _f[2]=4.2341065046 _f[3]=4.7229532216
2 _f[1]=2.5649493575 _f[2]=4.0342406382 _f[3]=4.4308167988
3 _f[1]=2.5649493575 _f[2]=4.1789920363 _f[3]=4.5849674787
4 _f[1]=2.6390573296 _f[2]=4.1399550735 _f[3]=4.6298627986
5 _f[1]=2.6390573296 _f[2]=4.1510399059 _f[3]=4.6298627986
6 _f[1]=2.4849066498 _f[2]=4.0483006237 _f[3]=4.4188406078
7 _f[1]=2.4849066498 _f[2]=4.091005661 _f[3]=4.4367515344
8 _f[1]=2.7080502011 _f[2]=4.1351665567 _f[3]=4.7229532216
9 _f[1]=2.5649493575 _f[2]=4.1351665567 _f[3]=4.4308167988
```

Comment: I **want** to use this approach.  But the collision risk is the same, no?  `data have;_n1='42';_n2=42;_f1='thistoo';run;`

Comment: There are no new variable names.

Comment: The only collision risk is between the temporary array name and **one** variable name. Choosing an unlikely array name would be pretty sufficient, and collisions would be logged as ERRORs (which is a good thing)

Comment: yes you are right, my question was badly phrased, the reason I didn't want new variable names was to avoid the risk of collision with existing variables.  This does answer the question as it's stated in the title

Answer (score 1):

The `PUT` statement does not accept a function invocation as a valid item for output.

A `DATA` step does not do columnar functions as you indicated with `max(age)` (so it would be even less likely to use such a function in `PUT`  ;-)

**Avoid name collisions**

My recommendation is to use a variable name that is highly unlikely to collide.

```
_temp_001 = somefunc(<var>);
_temp_002 = somefunc2(<var2>);
put _temp_001 _temp_002;

drop _temp_:;
```

or

```
%let tempvar = _%sysfunc(rand(uniform, 1e15),z15.);
&tempvar = somefunc(<var>);
put &tempvar;

drop &tempvar;
%symdel tempvar;
```

**Repurpose**

You can re-purpose any automatic variable that is not important to the running step.  Some omni-present candidates include:

- numeric variables:

  - `_n_`
  - `_iorc_`
  - `_threadid_`
  - `_nthreads_`
  - `first.<any-name>` (only tweak after `first.` logic associated with `BY` statement)
  - `last.<any-name>`
- character variables:

  - `_infile_`  (requires an empty `datalines;`)
  - `_hostname_`
- avoid

  - `_file_`
  - `_error_`

Comment: I like this approach, fair to say that a collision there would be somewhat unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be pretty safe choosing some unlikely to collide names.  An easy way to generate these and still make the code somewhat readable would be to just hash a string to create a valid SAS varname and use a macro reference to make the code readable.  Something like this:

```
%macro get_low_collision_varname(iSeed=);
  %local try cnt result;  
  %let cnt = 0;
  %let result = ;
  %do %while ("&result" eq "");
    %let try = %sysfunc(md5(&iSeed&cnt),hex32.);
    %if %sysfunc(anyalpha(%substr(&try,1,1))) gt 0 %then %do;
      %let result = &try;
    %end;
    %let cnt = %eval(&cnt + 1);
  %end;  
  &result
%mend;
```

The above code takes a seed string and just adds a number to the end of it.  It iterates the number until it gets a valid SAS varname as output from the md5() function.  You could even then test the target dataset name to make sure the variable doesn't already exist.  If it does build that logic into the above function.

Test it:

```
%let my_var = %get_low_collision_varname(iSeed=this shouldnt collide);    
%put &my_var;

data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  &my_var = 1;
  put _all_;
run;
```

Results:

```
Name=Alfred Sex=M Age=14 Height=69 Weight=112.5 C34FD80ED9E856160E59FCEBF37F00D2=1 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
Name=Alice Sex=F Age=13 Height=56.5 Weight=84 C34FD80ED9E856160E59FCEBF37F00D2=1 _ERROR_=0 _N_=2
```

This doesn't specifically answer the question of how to achieve it without creating new varnames, but it does give a practical workaround.